# php POST array not set

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post, form-submit

I am trying to collect data from the user in a form and display the data back to them.

I am using WAMP.

Here is my html code

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="submit.php">
<INPUT type="text" name="URL" size=17 value="http://">
<INPUT type="text" name="user" size=17>
<INPUT type="text" name="email" size=17>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
<INPUT type=reset value="Clear">
</form>
```

Here is my submit.php code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['URL'])){
    echo "set";
}
else
{ 
    echo "not set";  
}
?>
```

When I execute this,  I am always getting "not set" as the output.

Comment: `$_POST`, not `$POST`

Comment: There is a big difference in writing $POST and $_POST. $_POST is a superglobal variable.

Comment: its not working for $_POST also .

Answer (score 1):

It should be $_POST not $post, so your code should be :-

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['URL'])){
    echo "set";
}
else
{ 
    echo "not set";  
}
?>
```

Also your form tag should not contain `encytype="text/plain"` because PHP doesn't handle it (and it is not a bug)

```
Valid values for enctype in <form> tag are:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
```

So remove `encytype="text/plain"`

Answer (score 0):

Remove 
`ENCTYPE="text/plain"`

from the form

So the form should look like

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
```

And its $_POST not $POST

```
if (isset($POST['URL'])){
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['URL'])){
```

Here is an example of handling the form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if (isset($_POST['URL']) && $_POST['URL'] != ''){
            echo "set";
    }
    else
    { 
            echo "not set";  
    }
}
?>


<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="submit.php" >
<INPUT type="text" name="URL" size=17 value="http://">
<INPUT type="text" name="user" size=17>
<INPUT type="text" name="email" size=17>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
<INPUT type=reset value="Clear">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST))
{ 
    echo "set"; 
}
else
{
    echo "not set";
}
 ?>
```

try this